# How to interact with parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a parent layout which is linear layout. Inside this parentLayout I have a Child layout. Using this child layout I have created an array of buttons. My code looks like this:

**XML Layout:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/ParentLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
   
    <ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipview" android:layout_width="fill_parent"                                                                                                                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">  
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/liVLayout" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"             
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content">                                                               
        </LinearLayout>    
    </ViewFlipper>   
</LinearLayout>
```

code for java:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //Setup the Activity
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.calendar_frm); 
    
    LinearLayout layMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
    layMain.setOnTouchListener((OnTouchListener) this);  
}
```

**Method for crating array of buttons on child layout:**

```
public boolean initDay()
{
    LinearLayout layoutVertical = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liVLayout);
    LinearLayout rowLayout = null;
    
    LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1);

    //Create Button
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
    {
        rowLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        rowLayout.setWeightSum(7);
        layoutVertical.addView(rowLayout, param);   
        
        for(int j=0; j<7; j++)
        {
            m_pBtnDay[i][j] = new Button(this);             
            m_pBtnDay[i][j].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            rowLayout.addView(m_pBtnDay[i][j], param); 
            
           // m_pBtnDay[i][j].setOnLongClickListener(this);                         
          //  m_pBtnDay[i][j].setOnClickListener(this);
            
            m_pBtnDay[i][j].setOnTouchListener(this);
           
            //save button position
            m_pBtnDay[i][j].setTag(new CalendarForm(i , j));
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

My problem is that the childlayout contains an array of buttons that covers the parentlayout.

So any onListenerEvent that I want to invoke for the  parentlayout doesn't work on the part covered by the childlayout. In my case, I call onTouchEventListener on the parentLayout.

So what happens, is that the part there is not covered by the childlayout behave to the event but the ParentLayout covered by child layout doesn't behave to that event although it is a childLayout of the ParentLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is working as it is supposed to. For example if you put a piece of paper on top of a table then when you touch the paper the table will not know if it is touched since the paper handles the touch (forgetting about the pressure from the touch :))

The only way you can go about this is ensure that for a particular area the child should not handle the event - `return false`. Since the child view does not handle the event, it is then passed on to the view underlying it which is our parent view..

Here is some pseudo code to get you started.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        if(v == child){
            if((event.getX && event.getY) is within ParentArea){
                //return false so that the parent will get the event.
                return false;                    
            }
            else{
                //handle child event
            }
        }
        else if(v == parent){
            //handle event 
        }
        break;
    }

    return true;
}
```